# how do you get the query string in the blade laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to ask how do I get the query string that the user inputted to the blade?
ex: `localhost:8000/user/data/182?type=bank&name=bca#`
so my expectations, I will put query string into input form

```
<input type = "text" value = "from query string type>
<input type = "text" value = "from query string name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <input type = "text" value = "{{!empty(app('request')->input('type')) ? app('request')->input('type') : '' }}">
    <input type = "text" value = "{{ !empty(app('request')->input('name')) ? app('request')->input('name') : '' }}">
```

Comment: thank you sir, it's amazing,because there isn't too much code in the controller

Answer (score 1):

You need to set variable your query string is the default value:

```
class ExampleController
{
    public function example() {
        $query_string = [
            'type' => null,
            'name' => null,
        ]

        // check request has query string and assign 
        if (request()->has('type')) {
            $query_string['type'] = request()->get('type');
        }
        // check request has query string and assign 
        if (request()->has('name')) {
            $query_string['name'] = request()->get('name');
        }

        return view('example', compact('query_string'));
    }
}
```

and view example.blade.php:

```
<form action="{{ route('example') }}" method="get" id="form1"> 
   <input type = "text" value = {{ $query_string('type') }}>
   <input type = "text" value = {{ $query_string('name') }}>
<form/>
```